# How to make a procedural planet material with varied roughness of land and water in Cycles with Blender 2.8?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, materials, node-editor, procedural

I am trying to make a Earth-like planet in Blender 2.8.
I will try to explain my question with details if possible.
Here is the shader I am using in text form:

*[Noise Texture]*|Fac|>**|Fac|**[Color Ramp]>**|Base Color|**[Principlied]**|BSDF|**>**|surface|**[Material Output]

There are green and blue colors in the Color Ramp.

The thing I want to do is:

**low roughness on blue color**

**high roughness on green color**

The water needs to be like this:

[image]

The ground needs to be like this:

[image]

If you still do not understand, I want my planet to have reflective water, and a solid ground that are made with noise texture and color ramp.

Comment: Hi. I hope you do not mind my edit. If I changed anything not to your liking please edit the question and correct it further. I believe a descriptive title and some other minor corrections might improve the chances of getting good answers faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the factor node output of the noise texture and feed it into a color ramp object. Take the color output of the color ramp and feed it to roughness of the principled shader. Use the color ramp object to create a sharp gradient that cuts off at the same point as your land.  You can use the same color ramp to set a lot of different properties, granting you sophisticated control over land vs sea.

You can use a more complicated ramp to vary the land behavior vs altitude and other subtle shading effects.